# $\int _{\mathbb{R}^2}|x+ty|e^{-(x^2+y^2)/{2}}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I need to show that $\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^2}|x+ty|e^{-(x^2+y^2)/{2}}dxdy=\sqrt{8\pi (t^2+1)}$, for any given $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I've tried the substitution $\left\{\begin{matrix} u=x+ty & \\ 
v= x-ty & 
\end{matrix}\right.$ that didn't work.

Also, polar coordinates yield:
$ I=\left (\int_{0}^{\infty}r^2e^{-r^2/2}dr  \right ) \left (\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\cos\theta + t\sin \theta|  d\theta      \right ) $ which is already a better expression but I still don't think that it can lead to an answer.

Any other ideas?

Comment: can't you restrict yourself by symmetry to a quadrant of the plane where the absolute value is not necessary?

Comment: I think that actually works, either. I'll try that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution
$$ u = \frac{x+t y}{\sqrt{1+t^2}},\qquad v = \frac{t x-y}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} $$
works far better, leading to

$$ \sqrt{1+t^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |u| e^{-\frac{u^2+v^2}{2}}\,du\,dv = \sqrt{8\pi(1+t^2)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}u e^{-u^2/2}\,du = \color{red}{\sqrt{8\pi (1+t^2)}} $$
as wanted, by Fubini's theorem and parity.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of "cheating" by using properties of the Gaussian distribution, may be useful to others besides the OP:

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normal, the density of $(X,Y)$ is $\frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$, and $X+tY \sim N(0, 1+t^2)$. Then, if $Z$ is independent standard normal, $\sqrt{1+t^2}Z \overset{d}{=} X+tY$, so
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint |x+ty| e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} \mathop{dx} \mathop{dy}
&= \mathbb{E}|X+tY|\\
&= \sqrt{1+t^2}\mathbb{E} |Z|\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{2(1+t^2)}{\pi}}.
\end{align}
[The step $\mathbb{E} |Z|=\sqrt{2/\pi}$ can be obtained by integrating directly.]
Multiplying both sides by $2\pi$ gives your answer.